# How to make rsync skip existing files on destination

Tags: rsync

I have one Raspberry NAS and one backup server (192.168.25.25).
I would like to regularly backup the Raspebery NAS into the backup server where until now I have copied the files manually.

I drafted the following command to be run from the Raspberry NAS:

```
rsync -vv --ignore-existing -a --progress --stats -e ssh '/home/daniele/nas/Multimedia/' 'pippo@192.168.25.25:/share/Multimedia/'
```

but the files already existing on the destination server 192.168.25.25 are not skipped but are transferred from source to destination despite the use of the --ignore-existing flag.

What am I doing wrong?
Please help,
Daniele

Comment: Are you sure they're being transferred?

Comment: What's the destination filesystem type?

Comment: How does it behave if you change the order of two of your command-line options, from `--ignore-existing -a` to `-a --ignore-existing`?

Comment: They are transferred and the destination file system is a QNAP one, I guess ext4. Then I tried to change the order but nothing has changed